# Codename one: Buttons got changed after library updation

Tags: codenameone

I have built app using codename one.It was working fine but after library updated its suddenly got changed having problems in my buttons.Button text automatically cleared.I am not able to see any text on button.
I have built UI using codename one designer.
help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a regression triggered by a previous fix to a different regression. I committed a fix for it here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/98754e015c2a462dceb7bafbf4cd292ec9d73ed2

We should push out an update that should be on the servers in a couple of hours.